# Putting a term under the square root

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I want to put a term under the square root (but with Mathematica), such that
$$(1+t)^2\sqrt{1+\frac{t^3}{(1+t)^3}}$$
is transformed to
$$\sqrt{(1+t)^4+(1+t)t^3}.$$
I've tried all the forms of `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Factor`, with `Assumptions` ...

```
FullSimplify[(1 + t)^2 Sqrt[1 + t^3/(1 + t)^3]]
```

However, nothing returns the right answer. What can I do?

Comment: Note that the reason *Mathematica* doesn't do this automatically is because it's not true, in general: *Mathematica* treats all symbols as implicitly *complex* unless stated otherwise, and of course, $\sqrt{(1+t)^4} \neq (1+t)^2$ for all complex numbers.

Comment: @march, yes I see! But it's strange that simple pointer to `Reals` or even strictly to $t>0$ doesn't work!

Comment: Well, *Mathematica* also has some algorithm for deciding what it means to be in simplified form. Both the final and initial forms *and* the pathway between them is part of that algorithm, so it's difficult sometimes to know what it will consider the most simplified form.

Answer (score 4):

A simple rule does it

```
e1 = (1 + t)^2  Sqrt[1 + t^3/(1 + t)^3]
e2 = e1 /. a_.*Sqrt[b_ + c_] :> Sqrt[ a^2*b + a^2*c]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To see conditions when the above is valid, use Reduce (for real `t`)

```
Reduce[e1 == e2 && Element[t, Reals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above says for any real `t` except `t=-1` to avoid `(1+t)` being zero.

Comment: Just an observation. Suppose I take the initial expression as `a` and the simplified expected expression as `b`. Then if I use `SameQ[a,b]`, why does Mathematica answer `False`? Do we need to provide some other `$Assumptions` apart from `t` being Real?

Comment: @codebpr  FYI, I added Reduce result. You see it says for all `t`, but written in strange way.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be $t \neq -1$ instead of what `Reduce` says?

Comment: @codebpr  Yes, sure., That is what it means, i.e. it is saying `(1+t)` can _not_ be zero. For any other value it is ok. I do not know why it did not just say that. good point.  It is same thing, but computers likes to say things differently.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a transformation on top of the defaults that forces it:

```
expr = (1 + t)^2 Sqrt[1 + t^3/(1 + t)^3];
assum = FunctionDomain[expr, t]
FullSimplify[expr, assum, TransformationFunctions ->
    {Automatic, PiecewiseExpand[BitOr[1, Sign[#]], assum] Sqrt[FullSimplify[# #, assum]] &}]
```

> t < -1 || t ≥ -(1/2)
> Sqrt[(1 + t) (1 + 2 t) (1 + t + t^2)]

Comment: But what if `t` is not `Real`? Suppose I give `assum = FunctionDomain[expr, t, Complexes]`?

Comment: @codebpr Then the sign adjustment to would become `(-1)^Boole[Reduce[Sqrt[(1 + t)^4 (1 + t^3/(1 + t)^3)]/((1 + t)^2 Sqrt[1 + t^3/(1 + t)^3]) == -1, t]] // FullSimplify`, so you wouldn't really get a simplification

Comment: The code in your comment gives the error `The answer found by Reduce contains unsolved equation(s)`